# How to convert two sets of variables with pivot_longer function

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset with patients who all have 3 test scores on 3 different dates. The scores and dates are all separate variables at this time. To visualise the data I need to convert it (see below).

What the data set looks like now:

```
Patient     Score_1.  Score_2.  score_3.  date_score1.  date_score2.  date_score3. 
1.          15        10        11        0              4              28
2.          12        9         11        0              7              31
3.          13        7         9         0              5              25
```

What I need to convert the data set to:

```
Patient    Date.     Score. 
1.         0         15
1.         4         10
1.         28        11
2.         0         12
2.         7         9
2.         31        11
3.         0         13        
3.         5         7
3.         25        9
```

Example_data:

```
structure(list(patient = c(1, 2, 3), Score_1 = c(15, 12, 13), 
    Score_2 = c(10, 9, 7), Score_3 = c(11, 11, 9), Date_score1 = c(0, 
    0, 0), Date_score2 = c(4, 7, 5), Date_score3 = c(28, 31, 
    25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I have tried converting the data using pivot_longer and the closest I got to achieve what I want to is with the code below.

```
plotdata <- pivot_longer(
  example_data 
  , cols = -c(Patient, Score_1, Score_2, Score_3)
  , names_to = c( NA, "date_score")
  , names_sep = "_"
  , values_to = "Date"
)
```

[image]

#The start is good I would say. Now I need to add the corresponding scores into date_score but I can't seem to figure out how. I tried (and failed) using the code below.

```
plotdata <- pivot_longer(
  plotdata
  , cols = -c(patient, date_score, Date)
  , names_to = c( NA, "Score_")
  , names_sep = "_"
  , values_to = "Score"
)
```

[image]

If anyone has an idea how I can do the second step of converting the data please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `pivot_longer`, we can use `names_pattern` to capture the characters before the `_` and specify the `names_to` as `.value`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = contains("_"),
    names_to = ".value", names_pattern = "^([^_]+)_.*")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  patient Score  Date
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1    15     0
2       1    10     4
3       1    11    28
4       2    12     0
5       2     9     7
6       2    11    31
7       3    13     0
8       3     7     5
9       3     9    25
```

Comment: So it is possible with pivot_longer, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to handle this problem with `pivot_longer()` only, but I also failed..

Here's an alternative solution with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data) |> 
  melt(measure.vars=patterns(
    date="Date_",
    score="Score")) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  select(patient,date,score) |> 
  arrange(patient)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  patient  date score
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1     0    15
2       1     4    10
3       1    28    11
4       2     0    12
5       2     7     9
6       2    31    11
7       3     0    13
8       3     5     7
9       3    25     9
```

Comment: I finally got it working with this, Thank you!!!